# Is taking an 'citizenship' oath that you don't believe in Halal?

Tags: halal-haram, oaths

I have seen many friends (non-muslims included) who take citizenship oaths only to say later it was just a formality and that they do not believe in it. Among the reasons they give is that the oath may require them to consider enemies of their new nation their enemies (which mostly means Muslim countries) and abiding by the nation's law which may support Homosexuality, Riba & other deeds deemed 'Haraam' in Islam.

**What should my response be to such people?**

For example, the oath of allegiance to USA in 2016 is:

"I hereby declare, on oath, that I absolutely and entirely renounce and abjure all allegiance and fidelity to any foreign prince, potentate, state, or sovereignty, of whom or which I have heretofore been a subject or citizen; that I will support and defend the Constitution and laws of the United States of America against all enemies, foreign and domestic; that I will bear true faith and allegiance to the same; that I will bear arms on behalf of the United States when required by the law; that I will perform noncombatant service in the Armed Forces of the United States when required by the law; that I will perform work of national importance under civilian direction when required by the law; and that I take this obligation freely, without any mental reservation or purpose of evasion; so help me God."!

Comment: Nice query JazakAllah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A muslim needs to be a good human first, before being a good muslim. A person cannot be a muslim if he is not a good human.

Every good human believes 'Honesty is a best policy'. So, if you evaluate it logically, its haram. You have got to be honest with yourself, dont take an oath in which you dont believe in. You do have a choice to say no to their citizenship. You do have a choice to go to a land that has a constitution in which you believe. and they wont kill you for that.

Liars in Islam are classified as hypocrites (munafiq). And in the eyes of God the place and value of a hypocrite is far below than that of a non-muslim (kafir). So, dont pretent to be someone you dont. be honest, be good and be a muslim.

Answer (score 2):

Alhamdulillaah,my suggestion is that all the Muslims go back to the Islamic lands that they have abandoned for the unislamic West and take a pledge to Allah to reestablish the Islam that they have abandoned,remember the return is to Allah,what will be our answer then

Answer (score -1):

There is no contradiction between this oath and islam if you do not interpret it litterally. This is true for the oaths of most western country.

- It makes no reference to homosexuality, atheism, apostasy, or any particular aspect of the law. Besides, you can criticise the law as much as you want once you take it.
- It states that you should bear arms when required by the law. In that case, unless some country openly declares war to the us, you are safe, no mandatory service will be imposed to you.
- non combattant service should not be a problem.
- The mention "so help me god " does not mention which god. In a more strictly secular country, "god" would not be mentioned at all.
- The constitution you are asked to protect says that you have the freedom to practice your religion.

Unless you interpret islam as an obligation to beat up homosexuals on sight, you can take it. If you cannot live on the same continent than homosexuals, why are you thinking about taking this oath in the first place ?

In the case of the us, I would add is it such a good idea right now ?

*follwing downvote* : if you see a clear contradiction, please point it out in comments. I mean contradition with respect to the oath and constitution it refers to, not their current president.

Comment: Not sure who or why this was downvoted by someone. The reason I ask this question is because in Islam each & every action is preceded by an intention (niyah). With all due respect, from the points in your answer, it would appear that one would be insincere in taking that oath. Agreed that it doesnt mention any specific law but it does keeps the gate open. Also IMHO if you already intent to criticize the law later then agreeing to it while taking the oath would make you a hyprocrite, wouldnt it?

Comment: Btw your point to the "current president" (elect?) brought me a smile... thanks :)

Comment: @ Ahmed no, criticising the law later does not make you a hypocrite. Islam says you should respect the law of the country you live in. In western countries, critic is permitted, even encouraged, since it is the way they have to make the laws better. In theory, it makes sensible laws stay, and stupid or unfair ones disappear.

Comment: Yes, president elect...